# Regex add spaces around quotes if not exist?

Tags: regex, markdown

The problem is adding spaces around markdown inline code:

Transform this:

```
xxx`code1`xxx `code2`xxx `code3` xxx
```

to:

```
xxx `code1` xxx `code2` xxx `code3` xxx
```

My solution is

```
((?<![\s])`[^`]*?`(?![\s]))
```

But it doesn't match "in pair", here is the live version:

https://regexr.com/4t570

Answer (score 0):

You can match marked down code by capturing a string between backticks that is followed by an even number of backticks (0, 2, 4 etc.). Ignore any spaces either side of the string, and replace it with the string surrounded by a single space i.e. match:

```
\s*(`[^`]*`)\s*(?=(?:[^`]*`[^`]*`)*[^`]*$)
```

and replace with (`<space>` = space character

```
<space>$1<space>
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lcpwBD/1)

Note that this *requires* the backticks to be balanced (i.e. an even number in the string, and there not to be any escaped backticks (`` \` ``) in the string.

Comment: Did this answer your question? If not, could you provide more information to help answer it?